# How can I get the id of the particular modelform?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am new to Django. I am just learning to use forms and modelforms. Here I used modelforms to get two charfields(username and password) and saving it. What I wanted to do is to get the model id of that username. Below is the code. But I can't get the id.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from reg.models import registration, registrationform
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from django.template import RequestContext


def registration(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = registrationform(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            p = registration.objects.all()
            for loop in p:
                if loop.username == username:
                    id = loop.id
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('reg.views.thanks', args=(id)))
    else:
        form = registrationform()
    return render_to_response('registration.html', {'form' : form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def thanks(request, id):
        p = get_object_or_404(registration, pk=id)  
    return render_to_response('thanks.html', {'reg': p)
```

One more question. What is the model field for password?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
            form = registrationform(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                data =form.save()
                #...
                id = data.id
                #...
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('reg.views.thanks', args=(id)))
```

Comment: That's working. but when I pass it in reverse it shows
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: reverse() argument after * must be a sequence, not int

Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in reverse, line 473

Comment: No moguzalp..still I can't get it..jst check this error and plz tell me the reason by checking in my code for reverse.
Error:"Reverse for 'reg.views.thanks' with arguments '(16,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found."

Answer (score 0):

```
user = form.save(commit=False)
user.first_name = u'First name'
user.last_name = u'Last name'
user.save()
```

For password use password1 field

Comment: user = form.save() then use user.id

Answer (score 0):

How about changing your registration function to this:

```
def registration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = registrationform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            userdetails = form.save()
            user = userdetails.username
            val = registration.objects.get(username = user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('reg.views.thanks', args=(val.id)))
    else:
        form = registrationform()
        return render_to_response('registration.html', {'form' : form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I suggest you read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/

Answer (score 0):

Please could you paste your `urls.py`?

I recently had a problem almost exactly the same as this - it was just a typo there, I had the wrong value in in second field of the url function:

```
url(r'^people/thanks/(?P<person_id>\d+)$', 'people.views.thanks'),
```

Should have been:

```
url(r'^people/thanks/(?P<person_id>\d+)$', 'people.views.new'),
```